# Makefile C/C++ with function depending of environment

Tags: c++, c, function, makefile, environment-variables

I am struggling with the following problem :

I would like to use tput in my Makefile for color but it needs the environment variable $TERM ( and the echo alternative with \033[0;31m is not portable and will no behave the same way on all computers ).

When on an environment that does not have the variable, make fails and the program is not compiled.
I already tried searching for environment variable testing in a Makefile but with no success so far.

This is an example of what I would like to do :

```
define my_color
    @tput setaf $2
    @tput bold
    @echo $1
    @tput sgr0
endef

CC      = gcc

CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wextra

SRCS    = my_super_file.c

OBJS    = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

NAME    = super_programm

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(call my_color, "     Compiling $<", 2)
    $(CC) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)

clean:
   rm -rf $(OBJS)

fclean: clean
   rm -rf $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all re clean fclean
```

a more complete example here : https://github.com/Hellfire01/Makefile/blob/master/Makefile

both will work just fine any computer but not on my server

What I am trying to do is have only one Makefile capable of working on both my computer and my server, I tried looking at the function ifeq but I did not succeed in getting it to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this makefile illustrates what you want:

```
have_term := $(shell echo $$TERM)

ifdef have_term
define my_color = 
    @tput setaf $2
    @tput bold
    @echo $1
    @tput sgr0
endef
else
my_color = @echo $1
endif

all:
    $(call my_color, "Hello world", 2)
```

If `TERM` is defined in the environment then `make` prints `Hello World` in
green, otherwise in plain white.

See [7.2 Syntax of Conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer : it did not work as such because $TERM gets the value "dumb" when trying "env -i make" but it allowed me to get the answer ^^. Would you know why does $TERM take that value and if I should be careful with it ?

Comment: Extending this to check for `dumb` is simple enough. The real problem is that if the `TERM` value doesn't have the capability being requested `tput` errors and you'd have to check for *that* to be sure you avoided a "problematic" value of `TERM` to do this robustly.

Comment: And actually, you don't even need `$(shell)` here since `$(TERM)` is available inside `make` directly (as it is exported from the parent shell). (Though I suppose that might not be entirely reliable.)

Comment: @MatthieuRaynauddeFitte A *dumb terminal* is just a monochrome screen and keyboard, without any local compute capability (inc. graphics capability), such as used to connect me to the distant mainframe in the distant past. If `TERM` reports `dumb` about your server I'd assume the terminal can do  nothing but print monochrome text. [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43945/89291)
may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the issue here is just that you want make to ignore errors/failures from `tput` when it can't operate correctly and continue you can do that by sticking a leading `-` on the `tput` lines (the same as the leading `@`).

So either `@-tput ...` or `-@tput ...`.

This will cause `make` to see (and output) the errors but won't fail the target because of them.

From [Errors](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors) in the GNU Make Manual:

> To ignore errors in a recipe line, write a ‘-’ at the beginning of the line’s text (after the initial tab). The ‘-’ is discarded before the line is passed to the shell for execution.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> clean:
>     -rm -f *.o
> ```

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for but a very useful one, thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

@- won't work, you'll get lots of error messages.

Something like this would work, but you could defintely write this more elegantly.

```
have_term := $(TERM)
ifeq ($(TERM),dumb)
    have_term=
endif
ifdef have_term
    color_blue = @tput setaf 6
    color_end  = @tput sgr0
else
    color_blue =
    color_end  =
endif
```